# UIAlertController is giving error on turning off WiFi

Tags: ios, swift

UIAlertController is giving error on turning WiFi off

```
let networkIssueController = UIAlertController(title: "Error",
                                               message: "Unable to load data. Connectivity error!", 
                                               preferredStyle: .Alert)
let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
networkIssueController.addAction(okButton)
let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
networkIssueController.addAction(cancelButton)
self.presentViewController(networkIssueController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

error showing is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x10)`

What may be the cause for this error?

Comment: seems like there's no problem with your alertcontroller. Are you able to presentViewController this alert controller? You're lacking details here.

Comment: Try to make that alertview instance property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple alert view and this works perfectly. Try this out.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Test", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(cancel)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a separate alertView instance.